# Is it possible to prevent Intellij from automatically importing an entire package of classes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) Ultimate 2019.1 and very often when I hit `alt+enter` to add an import one some class `some.package.SomeClass` it adds `import some.package.*` instead of `import some.package.SomeClass`.

I was wondering if there is an option to have Intellij adding **only** single class imports.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible if you open `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports` and set value like 9999999 to `Class count to import with "*"` and `Names count to use static import with '*'` options.